# Singleton in plugin fails on AJAX call (Plugin initialzed again)

Tags: php, ajax

I am using the [Wordboot starters plugin](https://github.com/AlexandruDoda/Wordboot) to create my own plugin. This plugin uses the PHP `singleton` method to prevent multiple plugin initializations.

Right now, when a visitor sends a contact form, a pure [Javascript XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) `AJAX` call is executed to handle the contact request.

Everything works fine but I noticed the singleton is not working properly since for each AJAX request the plugin is executing the `__construct` of the main `Wordboot` class. This means everytime when such request is executed, the whole plugin is initialized again!

I used the `Wordpress REST API` and the usual way `wp_ajax` for executing AJAX calls but both methods makes this behaviour.

I was wondering if someone could explain me more about this, and how I could prevent a new plugin initialization when an AJAX call is executed?

I'm using the latest version of Wordpress.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using? A class written as a Singleton typically wouldn't have a `__construct` method.

Comment: Each AJAX request is a whole new request, so everything has to be loaded again, else none of your AJAX handlers or REST endpoints would be present. I sense there's a misunderstanding here about how PHP handles requests, there's no persistant process running like on a Node.js server

Comment: @Welcher The code can be found at https://github.com/AlexandruDoda/Wordboot/blob/master/wordboot/wordboot.php

Comment: @TomJNowell So there have to be a way not to re-initialize the whole plugin on AJAX calls, right? Maybe some checking if the request is an AJAX request, if so, route it to the right controller is something like that?

Comment: That’s not how PHP works. Every class is reinitialised on every request. If you’re doing something that should only ever be done once then it should be done in a plugin activation hook.

Comment: That's just how WordBoot is built, you can make it so things that don't need to load on AJAX don't load on AJAX, but that's not what you asked ( it's not very clear the way your question is worded )

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found a sorth of solution. I just check each new request of the request wants to acces `wp-json`, if so load the ajax based on the url otherwise initialize the plugin. Seems to work so far.

Thanks for the replys guys!